# Gradle import of app resources not successful in IntelliJ or Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I imported a gradle project.

The app module has 4 folders inside

foo
moo
app
boo

moo folder has resources for google play and boo folder has resources for custom table device 
They are both flavours inside app module settings.

This is error that I get:
https://gist.github.com/matej-snivam/02066be1ac8a85a6eeb0

```
Error:(165, 45) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/send_phone').

Error:(70, 39) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_width' with value '@dimen/size_236dp').
```

The error references either @drawable or @dimens

for example send_phone.png is inside boo/res/drawable-nodpi but somehow it is not included in project

also, boo/res/valuse has dimens xml with dimension

any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Just copy them your self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there were different gradle tasks, and Android studio was running build task instead of first running assemble task for flavour boo.

If you run into same problem, run `gradle tasks` to see if you have some tasks that will automatically merge the files

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

1. Check that the resources which make the error are in the folder of the module that requires them (maybe your are not importing the module with the resources into the one that requires the resources).
2. Clean project and rebuild project (I guess you did).
3. Delete manually all generated files in folder "build", and rebuild the project.

If your resources are in their folders, maybe it's a workspace refresh issue.

Comment: The thing is the module app has many subfolders. I am not familiar with android module and flavours structure that Is why I am asking this. It seems that boo and foo are two flavours. And that there should be some way of packaging either boo app or foo app with their respective res folders. I just don't know how to achieve that.